# How to stop downloading Resources for Web Application Load Testing using Loadrunner?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I'm performing Load testing of Web Applications using Loadrunner,while running the scripts it is downloading all the resources available for particular screen or pages because of this response time is taking more,Can anyone please help me how to control this type of problems in Web Application Load Testing using Loadrunner.

```
web_url("Search Customer",
"url=http://ipaddress:portnumber/searchCustomer",
"Url=Images/snapshot.jtl,
"Url=Images/file.css",
"Url=Images/jscript.js"
);
```

Comment: Since the resources are part of the page you absolutely must download them during a load test, otherwise you are not really testing anything. If you still think it is a good idea to remove them, just remove the appropriate line with the resource name from the script.

Comment: Please let us know where you're working so someone can come behind you and fix any issues on the resources you are not downloading (size, complexity, cache age, etc....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the **Run Time Settings** Menu > Under **Browser** > **Browser Emulation** > Uncheck the "**Download non-HTML resources**" option:

[image]

Comment: Now, how will you find issues associated with the performance of the static resources, such as too large, botched cache plan, etc...?